# Width of Android Scrollbar in ScrollView

Tags: android

I am customizing a `ScrollView` by changing the "look-and-feel" of its `Scrollbars`. I'm doing that through the following codes:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/quiz_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="23dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_pointer"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_blank" >
```

My drawable for `android:scrollbarTrackVertical` is 23x321. Here's my problem: When I run my application my vertical scrollbar becomes so thin (about 10px only)! It is not honoring the actual size of my drawable. But when I open it on the Graphical XML Designer in Eclipse, the scrollbar's width is just alright (no problem). The problem comes out when I run the application in the emulator.

Comment: What is your emulator screen size? This can be because of "dp" size of scrollbar

Comment: Try to set scroll bar size `23px`

Comment: I tried it. But it's not working.

Comment: What picture do you use for scroll bar? Can you add it to question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(@drawable/scrollbar_pointer@drawable/scrollbar_blank) Are these images of xml files ?? if xml files can u list their code here !